# How do I fix wp_enqueue_script call with misplaced parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dependencies

I wrote a plugin for Wordpress and I need to enqueue a couple of scripts which require jquery. This is my code:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script1', plugins_url( 'plugin-name/js/script1.js', array( 'jquery' ) ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'script2', plugins_url( 'plugin-name/js/script2.js', array( 'jquery', 'script1' ) ) );
```

My problem is that the scripts are loaded, but it seems that the correct order is not respected, since I get the error "jQuery is not defined" in the first script and "Object [object Object] has no method 'methodName'" in the second script, which calls a function defined in the first script. This happens on Wordpress 3.8, while on 3.5 is working correctly though.
Any ideas?

Comment: do you have a live example?

Comment: Ouch, I just noticed misplaced brackets, that was a silly mistake! Now everything's working, obviously!

Comment: You can answer your own question, or choose to delete it.